# Windows Forms Application menuStrip in Visual Studio 2017 is more covenient than 2019?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create Windows Forms Application and add a menuStrip item to my designer window. In VS 2017 you can simply click on the menuStrip and add items, but in VS 2019 you have to add all items manually trought properties -> data -> items. Am I right? Or I should turn on some property on to get back to that 2017 style of adding the elements?

VS 2017 menuStrip designing:

[image: VS 2017 menuStrip designing]

VS 2019 menuStrip designing (sooo uncomfy!):
[image]

So can I do something to get back to that convenient 2017 editing?

Comment: "Opinion based" is not quite right. The opinion here is the perception of "convenient". But the _question_ is how to get the "old" designer behavior in the new version of VS.

Comment: i have 2019 running and actually i can edit it exactly as in the above gif. Did you choose Core winforms?

Comment: I think also that this is a valid question and i don't quite understand the downvotes

Comment: As per Mong Zhu's comment.  I opened a form Targeting .Net framework 4.7 and the menu strip works in the '2017' mode.  I created a new winform project on .Net Core and it behaved as you you described above in the 'inconvenient' mode.  (I agree that 99% of the winform programmers would find this very inconvenient).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This unfortunate loss of comfort is not due to Visual Studio but to the Difference between Core and .NET Framework. If you create your Windowsforms project under the .NET framework then you will experience the comfort that is shown by your first gif.

If you choose .NET Core, then.... well you experience the loss of comfort. It's not the only loss of comfort that we have to deal with if we decide/are forced to move to Core. But nothing is more constant than change.

This is how it looks in a comparison:

Core:

[image]

.NET 4.7.2 (Zielframework means Target Framework, sorry for the non English version):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought about that I am creating wrong project :) I managed to fix this now

Comment: @vytaute glad I could help. I also did not know that before your post. :)